# How to create an additional authenticatable model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

*Okay so I know there are a ton of tutorials out there talking about changing the authentication to your liking, but I couldn't find one for my specific case. So here it goes:*

In one of my projects I've been using the standard authentication system that comes with Laravel. I have a **user model**, and each user has an email and a password. They also have roles and permissions and everything works as expected.

I also have a **client model**. There are projects and each project belongs to a client. Now there is a new requirement for the app, where clients should be able to login and see all of their projects.

Clients should login with a **username** (not email) and a **password**.

**My question is:** What steps are necessary to completely get this going. All I can find online are some pieces of the puzzle, but unfortunately I'm not able to put this together on my own. I know it involves creating a **user provider**, but that is only part of it. How do I hook up routes/controllers for this, how do I use the custom user provider, how can I use the Auth facade in addition to the standard "user" authentication (I will need to use both side by side)?

If someone knows of a comprehensive tutorial I will be happy to read that and apologize for this question ;-) Otherwise I will be very thankful for a little checklist of all the things I have to consider.

*PS: There a many reasons why I can't just use my user model with a special role or something like that. I need to use the client model for authentication.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel) which contains the gist of what you're looking for. The basics come down to something along these lines:

1. Create a new `Authenticatable` model
2. Adjust `auth.php` with new guards and providers
3. Adjust routing to take both models in account

I'm not sure how the `Auth` facades plays its role in this, but it might require some additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks @PtrTon, I will check that out